# how to work with label text in text field in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-web

1 My label text have some padding with border ,how to remove that space?
2 how to write label text inside the border in text field?
3 how to adjust alignment of label text in flutter?

[image]

Comment: ask one question only.. and add the code you tried

Comment: looks like zomato biker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) for the padding in the textformfield you should edit the contentPadding in Decoration, eg:

```
TextField(
   maxLines: 8,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,0,0), <--
      labelText: 'Description',
      labelStyle: txtHintStyle,
   )
 )
```

and put whatever you want like overriting it to 0.

2) remove the hint text if you defined already the label text, when you select the textformfield, the labeltext will go automatically over the label.

3) TextFormField offer the textAlign parameter, eg:

```
TextFormField(
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,    <--
  controller: _username,
),
```